# Bash math expression

Tags: bash, math, parameter-expansion

I need help with this its been busting my mind.

I have a read with a variable with integers `10 20 -30`.

All separated by white space. I try to change the minus to plus and save it onto another variable but it's not saving. If I can't change to plus I would like to remove it so then I can do:

```
var=$((${num// /+/}))
```

So it can add all integers.

This is what I have:

```
read num
echo $num
sum=$num | sed -e 's/-/+/g'
echo $sum
```

Comment: re: '*change the minus to plus and save it into another variable*': `num='10 20 -30' ; num2="${num//-/+}" ; echo "${num2}"` => `10 20 +30`

Comment: re: '*add all integers*': `echo "$(( ${num// /+} ))"` => `0` ; `echo "$(( ${num2// /+} ))"` => `60`

Answer (score 2):

Using standard POSIX variable expansion and arithmetic:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# Computes the sum of all arguments
sum () {
  # Save the IFS value
  _OIFS=$IFS

  # Set the IFS to + sign
  IFS=+

  # Expand the arguments with the IFS + sign
  # inside an arithmetic expression to get
  # the sum of all arguments.
  echo "$(($*))"

  # Restore the original IFS
  IFS=$_OIFS
}

num='10 20 -30'

# shellcheck disable=SC2086 # Intended word splitting of string into arguments
sum $num
```

More featured version with a `join` function:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# Join arguments with the provided delimiter character into a string
# $1: The delimiter character
# $@: The arguments to join
join () {
  # Save the IFS value
  _OIFS=$IFS

  # Set the IFS to the delimiter
  IFS=$1

  # Shift out the delimiter from the arguments
  shift

  # Output the joined string
  echo "$*"

  # Restore the original IFS
  IFS=$_OIFS
}

# Computes the sum of all arguments
sum () {
  # Join the arguments with a + sign to form a sum expression
  sum_expr=$(join + "$@")

  # Submit the sum expression to a shell's arithmetic expression
  # shellcheck disable=SC2004 # $sum_expr needs its $ to correctly split terms
  echo "$(($sum_expr))"
}

num='10 20 -30'

# shellcheck disable=SC2086 # Intended word splitting of string into arguments
sum $num
```

Comment: Care, playing with `IFS` could lead to unnatended behaviour!

Comment: Nice! +1 for POSIX compliant! Next step: create a function to avoid use of `set --` (ie don't touch script arguments).

Comment: @F.Hauri made it a function

Answer (score 1):

#### Simply: whipe last slash:

```
num="10 20 -30"
echo $((${num// /+}))
0
```

#### Some details

****Bash battern substitution*** has nothing common with so called *regular expression*. Correct syntax is:

```
   ${parameter/pattern/string}
```

> ... If pattern begins with /, all matches of pattern are replaced with string.
> Normally  only  the  first match  is  replaced. ...

See: `man -Pless\ +/parameter.pattern.string bash`

If you try your syntax:

```
echo ${num// /+/}
10+/20+/-30
```

Then

```
echo ${num// /+}
10+20+-30
```

Or even, to make this pretty:

```
echo ${num// / + }
10 + 20 + -30
```

But result will stay same:

```
echo $((  ${num// / + }  ))
0
```

Comment: If there is a single minus, the double slash is also redundant, if not exactly wrong.

Comment: @tripleee `10 + 20 + -30` is correct! (Spaces are optional) ... Even `10 - 20 - -30` is correct too!

Comment: @tripleee Maybe you prefer: `echo ${num// / + }` -> `10 + 20 + -30` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
sum=$num | sed -e 's/-/+/g'
```

With respect to what's present above, `sum=$num` and `sed` become two different commands. It's not grouped together as you wanted, which makes the `sed` ineffective.

Also, you'd need to `echo $num`

Solution is to group them together, like:

```
sum=`echo $num | sed -e 's/-/+/g`
```

OR

```
sum=$(echo $num | sed -e 's/-/+/g')
```

OR Rather, an alternate approach

```
sum=${num//-/+}
```

Comment: Avoid useless fork: `sed 's/X/Y/g' <<<"$varname"' instead of `echo $varname | sed ...`!